# How to ensure the uniquesness of global symbols and restric its scope in C?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Below is the trick used in Linux Kernel for per-cpu valuables.
As the comment says, it could acheive these two goals:

1.enforce scope.

2.ensure uniqueness, even the static ones.

Here is how the magic plays(For simplicity, I subsititude some MACRO's) :

```
/*
 * __pcpu_scope_* dummy variable is used to enforce scope.  It
 * receives the static modifier when it's used in front of
 * DEFINE_PER_CPU() and will trigger build failure if
 * DECLARE_PER_CPU() is used for the same variable.
 *
 * __pcpu_unique_* dummy variable is used to enforce symbol uniqueness
 * such that hidden weak symbol collision, which will cause unrelated
 * variables to share the same address, can be detected during build.
 */
 #define DECLARE_PER_CPU_SECTION(type, name, sec)                        \
 extern __attribute__((section(".discard"), unused))                     \
               char __pcpu_scope_##name;                                 \
 extern __attribute__((section(sec))) __typeof__(type) name

 #define DEFINE_PER_CPU_SECTION(type, name, sec)                         \
 __attribute__((section(".discard"), unused)) char __pcpu_scope_##name;  \
 extern __attribute__((section(".discard"), unused))                     \
             char __pcpu_unique_##name;                                  \
 __attribute__((section(".discard"), unused)) char __pcpu_unique_##name; \
 __attribute__((section(sec)))  __attribute__((weak))                    \
              __typeof__(type) name
```

**My questions are**

1. For Goal #1. How could it enforce scope? Does it work like this:

   When DECLARE* and DEFINE* exist in the **same traslation unit**, it turns the 
   variable in question to internal linkage,  and thus, any extra DECLARE* for 
   the same variable will trigger build failure(cause they disagree on linkage)

   But if this is true, then

   - How the interal-linkage-receivement works ? From C99 6.9.2.2(External object definitions), this happens only for **tentative definition**, but this case seems not **tentative definition**?
   - Wont't this break the **"One-definition-and-mutiple-declarations-are-OK"** rule?
2. For Goal #2, the two  __pcpu_unique_##name decalation(exactly, one is declaration, the other one is definition) seems play the same trcik as the  __pcpu_scope_##name, then how it 
   help to ensure the uniqueness ?

FYI, the code in question could be viewed here: 
http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9/include/linux/percpu-defs.h#L61

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is enforced by the compiler.  See the [ARM vmlinux.lds.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S), [vmlinux.lds.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h) and [percpu.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/asm-generic/percpu.h); the *linker file* is pre-processed to use *kernel* configuration variables.  The `".discard"` sections are a bunch of symbols that will cause a link conflict on multiple definitions; but they are *thrown away* and do not make it into a binary.

See the *macros* **PER_CPU**, **PER_CPU_FIRST**, **PER_CPU_SHARED_ALIGNED**, etc.  These macros only take a *type* and *name*.

Your *macro* expansion is not quite correct.

```
 #define DECLARE_PER_CPU_SECTION(type, name, sec)                        \
 extern __attribute__((section(".discard"), unused))                     \
               char __pcpu_scope_##name;                                 \
 extern __attribute__((section(PER_CPU_BASE_SECTION sec))) __typeof__(type) name
```

The *sec* parameters is actually a *sub-section*; note **PER_CPU_BASE_SECTION** and the string concatenation.

As I understand it, *It receives the static modifier...* seems misleading.  It would be better expressed as **If** *it receives...*.   So these cases are different,

```
static DEFINE_PER_CPU_PAGE_ALIGNED(... /* Cause error with DECLARE */
DEFINE_PER_CPU(unsigned int, irq_count) = -1; /* Fine with DECLARE */
```

In any case, this is not being enforced by the compilers, but by the *GNU linker* (or at least both) as it is important that these values are cache aligned and in some cases the cache size is configured by the **kbuild** infrastructure.

It is also important to note a preceding comment related to code generation,

```
 * s390 and alpha modules require percpu variables to be defined as
 * weak to force the compiler to generate GOT based external
 * references for them.  This is necessary because percpu sections
 * will be located outside of the usually addressable area.
 * This definition puts the following two extra restrictions when
 * defining percpu variables.
 *
 * 1. The symbol must be globally unique, even the static ones.
 * 2. Static percpu variables cannot be defined inside a function.
 *
 * Archs which need weak percpu definitions should define
 * ARCH_NEEDS_WEAK_PER_CPU in asm/percpu.h when necessary.
```

Ie, the `__attribute__((weak))` is being used not for symbol resolution but for code generation side effects.  There is an `#else` condition where the `weak` complication is not bothered with.

Now to answer your questions briefly,

> For Goal #1. How could it enforce scope?

Both a **static** and **non-static** declaration result when we have,

```
DECLARE_PER_CPU_PAGE_ALIGNED(int,foobar);
static DEFINE_PER_CPU_PAGE_ALIGNED(int,foobar);
```

> For Goal #2, ... `__pcpu_unique_##name`, then how it help to ensure the uniqueness ?

Multiple `weak` symbols do not cause errors.  The `__pcpu_unique_##name` is not `weak` so it is being used to enforce *uniqueness* as `weak` is being used for code generation reasons.

See [Gcc's function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) and search for weak, in case the normal purpose of weak is not understood.

Comment: For the morbidly interested, Google: [lkml+DECLARE_PER_CPU_SECTION+weak](https://www.google.ca/#q=lkml+DECLARE_PER_CPU_SECTION+weak)